# Menu item disappears

Tags: qt

In Qt Designer I added a new Main Window. \
There is a half finished menu there. I typed File and Service and pop-down menus.
So, my menu now looks like this:
 File
   \Exit
 Service
   \New game
   \Pause
   \About the program.

Well, it works. But when I, say, click Service, the pop down menus appear but the very Sevrice item disappears (as if is closed by a white rectangle).

What could it be?

Comment: Is this behaviour only in Qt Creator, or the running program?

Comment: In the running program.